# limit django fields queried in sql call to database by queryset

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a table with a blob and would like to exclude it from being in the sql call to the database unless specifically called for.  Out of the box django includes everything in the queryset.  So far the only way I have found to limit the field is to add a function to the view get_queryset()

```
def filter_queryset_fields(request, query_model):
    fields = request.query_params.get('fields')
    if fields:
        fields = fields.split(',')
        # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
        allowed = set(fields)
        existing = set([f.name for f in query_model._meta.get_fields()])
        values = []
        for field_name in existing & allowed:
            values.append(field_name)
        queryset = query_model.objects.values(*values)
    else:
        queryset = query_model.objects.all()
    return queryset


class TestViewSet(DynamicFieldsMixin, viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.TestData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.TestSerializer

    filter_backends = [django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_fields = ('id', 'frame_id', 'data_type')

    def get_queryset(self):
        return filter_queryset_fields(self.request, models.TestData)
```

and mixin to the serializer to limit the fields it checks

```
class DynamicFieldsMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DynamicFieldsMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if "request" in self.context and self.context['request'] is not None:
            fields = self.context['request'].query_params.get('fields')
            if fields:
                fields = fields.split(',')
                # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
                allowed = set(fields)
                existing = set(self.fields.keys())
                for field_name in existing - allowed:
                    self.fields.pop(field_name)


class TestSerializer(DynamicFieldsMixin,     rest_serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TestData
        fields = '__all__'
```

this seems like a lot of code for what it does.  Is there an easier way?

Comment: Check this [DRF Dynamically modifying fields example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django already have this right out the box. Just use [defer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#defer) or [only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/pt-br/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#only)

Defer will allow you the exclude a set of fields from the queryset:

```
MyModel.objects.defer('field_i_want_to_exclude')
```

While only allows you to say what fields you want on the queryset:

```
MyModel.objects.only('field_i_want1', 'field_i_want2')
```

Comment: This is not correct. The "only" will immediately load the columns you say and deferred the remaining ones.

Comment: Defer will skip the fields and not retrieve them from the db. It is on the docs.

Comment: Read my comment again.

Comment: I did, and it doesn't make a lot of sense. Sorry. If you don't mind to clarify.

Comment: ah, defer is what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: You can measure the performance of the only and defer vs values. Values is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Id do something like this for single, NON nested objects. For nested properties, you'll need more logic.

```
class DynamicFieldListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):

    def to_representation(self, data):
        """
        Code is a copy of the original, with a modification between the
        iterable and the for-loop.
        """
        # Dealing with nested relationships, data can be a Manager,
        # so, first get a queryset from the Manager if needed
        iterable = data.all() if isinstance(data, models.Manager) else data

        fields = list(self.child.get_fields().keys())
        iterable = iterable.only(*fields)

        return [
            self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
        ]


class DynamicSerializerFieldsMixin:

    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super().get_fields()
        raw_fields = set(self.context['request'].GET.get('fields', '').split(','))
        # If querysparams ?fields= doesn't evaluate to anything, default to original
        validated_fields = set(raw_fields) & set(fields.keys()) or set(fields.keys())
        return {key: value for key, value in fields.items() if key in validated_fields}

    @classmethod
    def many_init(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        meta = getattr(cls, 'Meta', None)
        if not hasattr(meta, 'list_serializer_class'):
            meta.list_serializer_class = DynamicFieldListSerializer
        return super().many_init(*args, **kwargs)
```

For examples see:

https://gist.github.com/kingbuzzman/d7859d9734b590e52fad787d19c34b52#file-django_field_limit-py-L207

Answer (score -1):

Use [values()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#values):

```
MyModel.objects.values('column1', 'column2')
```

Comment: This is not ideal to what op is trying to do, since `values` excludes the id, unless you pass it explicitly.

Comment: This is the most optimal answer.